# Can I make Voice/Video Call in Kiosk Desktop App with Microsoft Teams?

Tags: call, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I need to make a desktop application as kiosk that can make a Voice/Video calls to Microsoft Teams Clients, is this possible?

For example:

When a user clicks on a button on my kiosks desktop application, this button will call a customer service agent on Microsoft Teams client through a voice/video call.

I've checked the Microsoft Teams & graph API documentations and I didn't get my answers there, this is what I looked at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

If I can do that, would you please share with me the tutorial or the logic to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview) to see how Teams can help make a call using bots. Please let me know if that does not help you.

Comment: Hi @Gousia-MSFT, Thank you for your reply, actually what I need is to open the video/voice call from inside my application, even if I installed the MS. Teams clients in both machines, I don't need the MS. Teams client UI to show up to my client, I need my clients to call our customer service team from inside my application, so I need everything looks like it's coming from inside my application not from MS. Teams. what I understand from MS. doc. that MS. Bot will handle the calling action only between both clients but is it going to embed the calling videos or screen inside my application?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to call to Teams users from your own custom desktop app without Teams license.

I'm afraid Microsoft Teams doesn't support custom built apps that call into Teams app currently.

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) you have found shows how to create a call for your service application (bot). But the bot needs to be used in Teams. It does not apply to the desktop app.

Comment: Hi @Allen Wu, Thank you for your reply, actually what I need is to open the video/voice call from inside my application, even if I installed the MS. Teams clients in both machines, I don't need the MS. Teams client UI to show up to my client, I need my clients to call our customer service team from inside my application, so I need everything looks like it's coming from inside my application not from MS. Teams. what I understand from MS. doc. that MS. Bot will handle the calling action only between both clients but is it going to embed the calling videos or screen inside my application?

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do not support initiating a call to Microsoft Teams user from an external app. You could [deeplink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat) and open a chat with the user but not call.